# Using scanf for reading specific words

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to look up for the most frequent word in a text. In my program,  I input some words some texts. The words and texts are separate by "-----"(I need to search for the most frequent word in my program).

However, I found that when the program search for words in the text. It seemed that it can not run out of the loop(I got time limited exceeded on PC^2). Then, I found that the problem comes from this function(I got Wrong answer error if I annotate this function). Does I misunderstand the usage of `scanf` or miss some other condition?

```
void inputTextTxt(void) {

  for (;;) {
   // toss all non-alpha-numerics
   scanf("%*[^a-zA-Z0-9_]");

   int cnt = scanf("%2047[a-zA-Z0-9_]", tmp);
   if (cnt != 1) {
     break; // or return
   }

   for (size_t i = 0; i < dic_actual_num; ++i) {
     if (strcmp(dicWord[i], tmp) == 0) {
       dicWcount[i]++;

     }
   }
  }
}
```

- The character which is not digit, alphabet, and '_' should be treated as space
- The longest length of each line is 1024

### Other parts of my code

```
char tmp[2048];
char **dicWord;
int *dicWcount;
int dic_assume_num = 1, dic_actual_num = 0;

void inputDicTxt() {

    char divider[6] = "-----";
    dicWord = malloc( dic_assume_num * sizeof( char* ));

    for (;;) {

        scanf("%*[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]");
        int cnt_divider = scanf("%2047[-]", tmp);
        int cnt_alphaNumerics = scanf("%2047[a-zA-Z0-9_]", tmp);

        if (cnt_divider != 1 && cnt_alphaNumerics != 1)
            break;

        else if (cnt_divider) {
            if (strcmp(tmp, divider) >= 0) {
                dicWcount = calloc(dic_actual_num,  sizeof(*dicWcount));
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (cnt_alphaNumerics) {
            if (dic_actual_num >= dic_assume_num) {
                dic_assume_num *= 2;
                dicWord = realloc( dicWord, dic_assume_num * sizeof( char* ));
            }
            dicWord[dic_actual_num++] = strdup(tmp);
        }
    }
}


int main() {

    inputDicTxt();
    inputTextTxt();

    int mostNum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dic_actual_num; ++i)
        if (dicWcount[i] > dicWcount[mostNum]) 
            mostNum = i;

    // print out the most frequent word and its number
    printf("%s %d\n", dicWord[mostNum], dicWcount[mostNum]);


    for (int i = 0; i < dic_actual_num; ++i)
        free(dicWord[i]);
    free(dicWord);
    free(dicWcount);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I've changed from `while(feof(!stdin))` to `for(;;)` in my code, but I still get TLE on the judging system

Comment: Please also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/694576

Comment: `scanf()` is a reading function, it does not compare anything. the first argument of scanf has to be a *format identifier* cf

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: @LINPOHSIEN Where is `tmp` defined?

Comment: @chux I just added it in other parts of code!

Answer (score 0):

> Do I misunderstand the usage of `scanf` or miss some other condition?

Be sure to review [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/694576) @alk

Yet in this case, code uses `while (!feof(stdin))` *almost* in an acceptable functional fashion.  So the issue may lie elsewhere.  IAC, avoid `while (!feof(stdin))` for its weaknesses and usual IO problem magnetism.

---

It is not clear why OP's code is in an apparent infinite loop (other than a rare input error or other UB like `tmp` too small) - even with the unusual code `while (!feof(stdin)) {`.

Yet below is similar code, that should more cleanly operate/debug.

OP is using `while (!feof(stdin))` in a precarious manner that can cause an infinite loop should code loop without reading a character.  Example: input error.

Instead of `while (!feof(stdin))`, check the return value from `scanf()` that saves data.  Do not simply check for boolean-ness like with `if (scanf("%2047[a-zA-Z0-9_]", tmp)`.  Check its value.

```
void inputTextTxt(void) {
  for (;;) {
   // toss all non-alpha-numerics
   scanf("%*[^a-zA-Z0-9_]");

   char tmp[2048]; 
   int cnt = scanf("%2047[a-zA-Z0-9_]", tmp);
   if (cnt != 1) {
     break; // or return
   }
   for (size_t i = 0; i < dic_actual_num; ++i) {
     if (strcmp(dicWord[i], tmp) == 0) {
       dicWcount[i]++;
       // I'd expect a `break;` here as once a match is found, 
       // could another be found?   Why keep looking?
     }
   }
  }
}
```

---

Pedantically, scan set ranges like `"%[a-z]"` are not universally implemented - it is *implementation-defined* behavior.  Highly portable code would require `"%[abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]"`. Most system understand `"%[a-z]"` as hope, so I doubt this is OP's problem.

---

From a style point-of-view, `if (scanf("%2047[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", tmp)); else if` is misleading - it looks like a problem.  If code remains with this, use `{;}` to clearly demarcate it.

```
if (scanf("%2047[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", tmp)) {
  ;
} else if ...
```

Comment: I've changed from `feof(!stdin)` to `for(;;)` in all of my codes. But I still got the same error. Do you have any other suggestions? Other parts of my code are posted.

Comment: i thinks `"%[a-z]"` is fine because it goes well in a test. However, it fails in another one.

Comment: Curious your edit coded `else if (scanf("%2047[a-zA-Z0-9_]", tmp)` and not heeded advice [Check its value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114994/2410359).  Why follow the `if()` block when `EOF` is returned?  Same for `if (scanf("%2047[-]", tmp))`.

Comment: Does it look better now? I check their value before `if` statement, when `EOF` is returned, it will break

Comment: @LINPOHSIEN `if (cnt_divider != 1 && cnt_alphaNumerics != 1)` has 4 combinations: `F&&F`, `F&&T`, `T&&F`, `T&&T`, You code does not work well for `F&&T`, `T&&F`. so "when EOF is returned, it will break" is false.